# HtmlUnit to view source

Tags: java, htmlunit

HtmlUnit for Java is great but I haven't been able to figure out how to view the full source or return the source of a web site as a string. can anyone help me with this?

I know the follow will read the site but now I just want to return the source to a string.

```
HtmlPage mySite = webClient.getPage("http://mysite.com");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From looking through the [API](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html), my thought would be:

```
mySite.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
```

Comment: the `toString()` method will definitely not work, I am not sure about the second though. Sounds like it might work but I have never tried it.

Comment: mySite.getWebResponse().getContentAsString(); works! it returns all of the source as if you chose "view source" from the page context menu! Thanks!

Comment: That is what the `asXml()` method does on HtmlPage. This may be the "accepted" answer, but that is not the way HtmlUnit intended you to get that information.

Comment: `asXml()` and `page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString()` is not exactly the same, as I just noticed. The former would remove the `<!DOCTYPE html>` and replace it with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. There may be other differences too, like an altered source tree, so beware.

Comment: Yes, it returns HTML, but isn't it just original page source, before running JavaScript on it?

Comment: page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString() does not run javascripts. 

So you will not get the required data, since most websites nowadays run on javascript based programming languages or Ajax. 

mySite.asXml() is better.

Answer (score 15):

```
String pageSource = myPage.asXml();
```

That will get you the full HTML source of the web page.

```
String pageText = myPage.asText();
```

That will get you all of the visible text on the page, including line breaks/white space. It would be the same if you were on the page in your browser and `Ctrl+A` then `Ctrl+V` into a variable.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried `mySite.asXml()`? Or you can do `mySite.getDocumentElement().toString()`